# Access to head tag in content pages (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout

I want to access to `<head>` tag section in my content pages (ASP.NET MVC).
For example, I want to put a CSS file link in the `<head>` tag in only a few content pages. How do I do this?

Comment: check this [html head](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp)

Comment: That's what sections are for.

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant. I wanna access to head tag in CONTENT PAGES (ASP.NET MVC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use sections.

In your shared layout, usually _Layout.cshtml, add an RenderSection like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
     @RenderSection("css", required: false)
</head>
```

Then in the content page you want to apply your css to, add the following

```
@section css{
    <!-- whatever stylesheets you want to link to your content page-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SomeStyles.css">
}
```

Now when your content page is rendered your page specific css will be added.